# uniq for Enumerator::Lazy

Tags: ruby

I am processing something with lots of repeated lines:

```
# => [ [1, "A", 23626], [1, "A", 31314], [2, "B", 2143], [2, "B", 5247] ]
puts xs

# => [ [1, "A"], [2, "B"] ]
puts xs.uniq{ |x| x[0] }.map{ |x| [x[0], x[1]] }
```

But **xs** is huge. I'm trying to load it lazily, but **Enumerator#Lazy** does not have an **uniq** method.

How do I do achieve this lazily?

Comment: Are repeated lines always consecutive?

Comment: No. I did find a lazy squeeze on Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
module EnumeratorLazyUniq
  refine Enumerator::Lazy do
    require 'set'
    def uniq
      set = Set.new
      select { |e|
        val = block_given? ? yield(e) : e
        !set.include?(val).tap { |exists|
          set << val unless exists
        }
      }
    end
  end
end

using EnumeratorLazyUniq
xs = [ [1, "A", 23626], [1, "A", 31314], [2, "B", 2143], [2, "B", 5247] ].to_enum.lazy

us = xs.uniq{ |x| x[0] }.map{ |x| [x[0], x[1]] }
puts us.to_a.inspect
# => [[1, "A"], [2, "B"]]
# Works with a block

puts us.class
# => Enumerator::Lazy
# Yep, still lazy.

ns = [1, 4, 6, 1, 2].to_enum.lazy
puts ns.uniq.to_a.inspect
# => [1, 4, 6, 2]
# Works without a block
```

This is straightforward implementation using `Set`; this means any uniq'd values (i.e. things like `[1, "A"]`, but not stream elements themselves such as `[1, "A", 23626]`) will take up memory.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to run a benchmark on the two methods I suggested and on @Amadan's method. The results speak for themselves.

**Benchmark code**

```
require 'benchmark'

module EnumeratorLazyUniq
  refine Enumerator::Lazy do
    require 'set'
    def uniq
      set = Set.new
      select { |e|
        val = block_given? ? yield(e) : e
        !set.include?(val).tap { |exists|
          set << val unless exists
        }
      }
    end
  end
end

using EnumeratorLazyUniq

def amadan(xs)
  xs.uniq{ |x| x[0] }.map{ |x| [x[0], x[1]] }
end
```

```
require 'set'

def cary_set(arr)
  first = Set.new
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |(a0, a1, *_), b|
    unless first.include?(a0)
      first << a0 
      b << [a0, a1]
    end
  end
end
```

```
def cary_hash(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) { |(a0, a1, *_), h|
    h[a0]=[a0, a1] unless h.key?(a0) }.values
end
```

**Test data**

```
n_uniq = 10_000
n_copies = 100
tot = n_uniq * n_copies

xs = tot.times.map { |i| [i % n_uniq, 0, 1] }
```

**Run Benchmark**

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("cary_set ") { cary_set(xs)  }
  x.report("cary_hash") { cary_hash(xs) }
  x.report("amadan   ") { amadan(xs)    }
end
```

**Results**

```
Unique elements: 200,000
Number of copies of each unique element: 5

Array size: 1,000,000
       user     system      total        real
cary_set   0.980000   0.030000   1.010000 (  1.018618)
cary_hash  0.980000   0.010000   0.990000 (  0.982508)
amadan     0.590000   0.010000   0.600000 (  0.597249)


Unique elements: 100,000
Number of copies of each unique element: 10
Array size: 1,000,000

       user     system      total        real
cary_set   0.920000   0.030000   0.950000 (  0.942539)
cary_hash  0.630000   0.020000   0.650000 (  0.642367)
amadan     0.470000   0.000000   0.470000 (  0.478658)


Unique elements: 50,000
Number of copies of each unique element: 20
Array size: 1,000,000

       user     system      total        real
cary_set   0.910000   0.020000   0.930000 (  0.932277)
cary_hash  0.570000   0.000000   0.570000 (  0.575439)
amadan     0.410000   0.010000   0.420000 (  0.417695)
```

```
Unique elements: 1000000
Number of copies of each unique element: 10
Array size: 10000000

       user     system      total        real
cary_set  12.660000   0.270000  12.930000 ( 12.962183)
cary_hash  7.730000   0.060000   7.790000 (  7.797486)
amadan     6.640000   0.060000   6.700000 (  6.707706)
```

Comment: I'm surprised the lazy version is actually faster than a loop. The reason I wanted lazy was ease of maintenance (quite simpler and more readable) and incredibly straightforward change if the method existed (IO.readlines -> IO.foreach.lazy). Either is already a huge improvement on memory usage from the eager functional version (O(n) -> O(1)).

Answer (score 1):

Why not something simple?

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def extract(arr)
  first = Set.new
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |(a0, a1, *_), b|
    unless first.include?(a0)
      first << a0 
      b << [a0, a1]
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [ [1, "A", 23626], [1, "A", 31314], [2, "B", 2143], [2, "B", 5247] ]
extract(arr)
  #=> [[1, "A"], [2, "B"]]
```

**Alternative**

A variant of this is:

```
def extract(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) { |(a0, a1, *_), h|
    h[a0]=[a0, a1] unless h.key?(a0) }.values
end
```

I would expect performance to be about the same, but the hash uses more memory, because of `values`

Comment: It is not at all more simple than mine, but it is more specific, and not reusable at all, and doesn't preserve the laziness. Aside from that, we are doing the exactly same thing - even the code size is the same (10 lines), aside from the scaffolding where I set up the refinement.

Comment: @Amadan, Yes, I agree; Would you expect Ruby to include more lazy methods, such as your `uniq`, in future versions?

Comment: I don't know, I don't set policies. And it is easy enough to add, in any case, so I don't really care. :)

Comment: This is similar to what I did in the real code because I didn't know how to implement uniq. I had to refactor all functional code because of this, but it did indeed work.